# The type provider 'FSharp.Data.SqlCommandProvider' reported an error: System.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform

Tags: f#, type-providers

I'm trying to create a small F# script that will be using FSharp.Data.SqlClient or other SQL Type Prodiver. I also tried SQLProvider. I always get the following error :

The type provider 'FSharp.Data.SqlCommandProvider' reported an error: System.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform.

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 with .NET 6. I also tried with .NET 4.7.2.

Comment: Try Microsoft.Data.SqlClient. The System.Data.SqlClient should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 2):

The maintainer of the project gave me a fix for the issue : https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Data.SqlClient/issues/423.

I had to force the evaluation of the System.Data.SqlClient nuget with ";;" :

```
#r "nuget: System.Data.SqlClient";;
```

at the beginning of the script.

@BentTranberg, the maintainer said he is evaluating the change to Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.